# Can't get Python Selenium to open a webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to programming, but I wanted to learn to use the selenium module. I use pycharm for my programs. I have been following along in the Automate the Boring Stuff With Python book. I have tried to use Firefox as well as IE and Chrome. Here is the code that I have tried which is given in the book:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://nostarch.com')
```

and the error code:

```
C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe     C:/Users/Matt/PycharmProjects/untitled/Bing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-  packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Matt/PycharmProjects/untitled/Bing.py", line 5, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x000002C3D9235160>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
self.stop()
File "C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

I have tried some of the other suggestions that were given on this site, but couldn't manage to get it to work. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Update your selenium package. Run `pip install -U selenium`.

Comment: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: I had the same issue yesterday. You will need to update your `Firefox` too

Comment: How do I get 'geckodriver' into PATH? (sorry I'm still trying to learn all this stuff. never programmed before) Also, my Firefox should be up to date as I  just downloaded the most recent version today. Thanks again

Comment: After messing around with things, I got it to work. Thank you all for the help